# What are some good ways of marketing a Bitcoin related service to Bitcoin users?

Tags: services, business, marketing

What is a brief summary of some good ways of promoting a Bitcoin related service? This could include:

- Bitcoin Service Directories
- Forums
- Advertising
- Mailing Lists
- ???

The target audience is people who have bitcoin and know how to use it.

To avoid this question being too broad and requiring answers that are too long, I suggest keeping any summary of each item brief.

Answer (score 1):

The folks at bitcoin.it run a moderated listing, https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade, which you can list at.  Another way is to work directly on reddit (r/bitcoin) and http://www.bitcointalk.org/.

Answer (score 0):

There are few types of Bitcoin marketing off the top of my head

1. People who have Bitcoin and know how to use it.
2. People who heard of Bitcoin (in Forbes etc) and are afraid of it.
3. People who hear of Bitcoin (also in Forbes etc) and love it.
4. People who don't know Bitcoin but either { Like investment | gambling | Technology | financial theory }

Your question is too broad, so you will need to narrow down who your target audience.  Please revise your question, or else people on this site (potentially myself included) will vote to close the question as being "too broad".

(though I hope the closers give you time to read and update your question)

Answer (score 0):

You can use all traditional SEO tools and services for targeted audience to improve your site in listings and accumulate traffic.

Additionally I could recommend using various micro tasks  such as blog posting and others to put as many links to your site on the web.

Answer (score -1):

Post your website on Paid To Click websites dedicated to Bitcoin and select a good time for viewing your ads.

Example: On BitcoBoom (http://bitcoboom.com), you can start a campaign of 1000 users view for $1. Selecting 20-30 seconds to view your website will increase interest in your website ;)